# Encurtando nome de pessoas

Tags: php

Preciso de um script que encurte nome de pessoas.

Por exemplo:
Nome: Fernando José Silva Machado

Com o script ele corte os sobrenomes e deixe só a iniciais e o ultimo sobrenome

Ficaria assim:
Nome: Fernando J. S. Machado

Tenho um sistema para cadastro de pessoas e geraçao de carteiras de associados que pega os nome, ai gostaria que escutasse os nomes que possuam mais de um sobrenome, mantenha o ultimo por extenso e os outros com a inicial e um ponto.

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Encontrei esse script porém ele pega o primeiro e o ultimo, diferente de mim que quero manter as inicias no meio.

```
function nome_sobrenome($nome_todo) {
$nomes = explode(' ', $nome_todo);
if(count($nomes) === 1) { // caso alguém tenha um só nome
    return $nomes[0];
}
return $nomes[0]. ' ' .$nomes[count($nomes) - 1];
}
```

Comment: Como a pergunta está marcada como pendente, não posso postar a resposta aqui. Mas talvez esse código lhe ajude. https://pastebin.com/SmzzefAN

Comment: Isso ai maninho, exatamente o que eu queria. muito obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha sugestão é usar `mb_convert_case` (**que permitirá suportar os acentos**) para normalizar e `preg_split` para dividir

> **Nota:** para usar funções `mb_` é necessário ativar o [`mbstring`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)
>
> No php.ini remova o `;` a frente do (se for Windows):
>
> de `;extension=php_mbstring.dll` para `extension=php_mbstring.dll`
>
> se for Linux:
>
> de `;extension=mbstring.so` para `extension=mbstring.so`
>
> se for **PHP7.2**:
>
> de `;extension=mbstring` para `extension=mbstring`

```
<?php
/**
 * Encurta nomes do meio com suporte para unicode e acentos
 *
 * @param string $name        Define nome para ser encurtado
 * @param array|null $ignore  Nomes/palavras que NÃO devem ser encurtados
 * @return string $encode     Define a codificação do nome (opcional)
 */
function mb_shorten_name($name, array $ignore = null, $encode = null)
{
    $ignore = $ignore === null ? array( 'de', 'da', 'do', 'dos' ) : $ignore;

    //Converte para case-title
    if ($encode) {
        $name = mb_convert_case($name, MB_CASE_TITLE, $encode);
    } else {
        $name = mb_convert_case($name, MB_CASE_TITLE);
    }

    //Divide a string
    $names = preg_split('#\s+#', $name);

    $j = count($names);

    // caso alguém tenha um só nome
    if ($j === 1) return trim($name);

    //Acaso só tenha menos de 3 nomes
    if ($j < 3) return implode(' ', $names);

    $j--;

    $rebuild = array( $names[0] );

    for ($i = 1; $i < $j; $i++) {
        $ex = $encode ? mb_strtolower($names[$i], $encode) : mb_strtolower($names[$i]);

        if (in_array($ex, $ignore)) {
           $rebuild[] = $ex;
        } elseif ($encode) {
           $rebuild[] = mb_substr($names[$i], 0, 1, $encode) . '.';
        } else {
           $rebuild[] = mb_substr($names[$i], 0, 1) . '.';
        }
    }

    $rebuild[] = $names[$j];

    return implode(' ', $rebuild);
}

var_dump(mb_shorten_name('joão marques almeida de castro filho')); # João M. A. de C. Filho
var_dump(mb_shorten_name('maria gimenez almeida alburqueque da Silva')); # Maria G. A. A. da Silva
```

Note que eu adicionei um parâmetro adicional chamado exceções para nomes que não devem ser encurtados, como `de`, `do` e `da`, você pode customizar, por exemplo adicionei `von` a exceção:

```
mb_shorten_name('Victor von Doom Junior', array( 'von' ))
```

Irá retornar:

> Victor von D. Junior

Note também que o terceiro parâmetro se chama `$encode`:

```
mb_shorten_name($name, [array $ignore, [$encode = null])
```

E você pode ajustar ele para diferentes codificações, ou pode até tentar detectar a codificação com `mb_detect_encoding`, um exemplo se tiver certeza do tipo de codificação que veem:

```
var_dump( mb_shorten_name($texto, null, 'UTF-8') ); # se a sua string for UTF-8

var_dump( mb_shorten_name($texto, null, 'ISO-8859-1') ); # se a sua string for ISO-8859-1
```

**Exemplo no Rep.it:** https://repl.it/@inphinit/mbshortenname

---

Se os nomes **não** tiverem acentos ou isto não for um problema pode simplesmente tentar usar:

```
<?php
/**
 * Encurta nomes sem acentos e com caracteres ASCII
 *
 * @param string $name    Define nome para ser encurtado
 * @param array  $ignore  Nomes/palavras que devem ser encurtados
 */
function shorten_name($name, array $ignore = array( 'de', 'da', 'do', 'dos' ))
{
    //Converte para case-title
    $name = ucwords(strtolower($name));

    //Divide a string
    $names = preg_split('#\s+#', $name);

    $j = count($names);

    // caso alguém tenha um só nome
    if ($j === 1) return trim($name);

    // Acaso só tenha 2 nomes
    if ($j < 3) return implode(' ', $names);

    $j--;

    $rebuild = array( $names[0] );

    for ($i = 1; $i < $j; $i++) {
        $ex = strtolower($names[$i]);

        if (in_array($ex, $ignore)) {
           $rebuild[] = strtolower($names[$i]);
        } else {
           $rebuild[] = substr($names[$i], 0, 1) . '.';
        }
    }

    $rebuild[] = $names[$j];

    return implode(' ', $rebuild);
}

var_dump(shorten_name('james bond de morais junior')); # James B. de M. Junior
var_dump(shorten_name('Kate Jennifer Bethan da Silva')); # Kate J. B. da Silva
```

**Exemplo no Rep.it:** https://repl.it/@inphinit/shortenname

Comment: Uma coisa, se o nome tiver as palavras `da`, `de`, `do`, exemplo "Miguel dos Santos Sobrinho" como ficaria?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic boa ideia para uma nova implementação, o que acha melhor, omitir ou criar um esquema de exceção?

Comment: Então, eu acho que ele não teve essa previsão no código, tem que ter exceção para ficar completo.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic coloquei como um array opcional nos parâmetros

Comment: Chique ... !...

Answer (score 2):

Uma função que pega o primeiro e o último nome, e abrevia os do meio, se houver. Remove palavras como "de", "do", "dos", "da", "das" e "e":

Exemplos:

- Maria Pereira dos Santos -> Maria P. Santos
- Virgulino Ferreira da Silva -> Virgulino F. Silva
- Maria Santos -> Maria Santos
- Antonio de Carvalho Souza Filho -> Antonio C. S. Filho
- Maria das Dores Costa -> Maria D. Costa

**Código:**

```
function nomeAbrev($nometodo){

   $pattern = '/ de | do | dos | da | das | e /i';
   $nome = preg_replace($pattern,' ',$nometodo);
   $nome = explode(' ', $nome);

   $nomes_meio = ' ';

   if(count($nome) > 2){
      for($x=1;$x<count($nome)-1;$x++){
         $nomes_meio .= $nome[$x][0].'. ';
      }
   }

   $nomeabreviado = array_shift($nome).$nomes_meio.array_pop($nome);

   return $nomeabreviado;

}

echo nomeAbrev('nome');
```